# How to set environment variables for Java

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables

I have inserted the following lines in `.bash_profile`

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/jun/Downloads
export PATH=$PATH:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

and the changes did take effect

[image]

However, when I try to access the environment variable with the following method

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"));
```

The result is **NULL**

Why is that?

Note: The application is ran with Eclipse.

Comment: How are you running the java application?

Comment: As a side note, you're setting `PATH` in your `.bash_profile` (and setting it to a literal string because you missed out a `$` before `GOOGLE`) but then you're trying to read `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in your `echo` command and your app. However if the `echo` command is working, I would expect your app code to also work, if it's being run in the same environment.

Comment: @Azquelt I am running the java app with eclipse. I printed out all environment variables using the method provided in the answer of Leo R. but couldn't see GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS there, but when I echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in the terminal the result come out.

Comment: That's important information, running from eclipse makes a big difference, see my answer below.

Comment: Can you please run your java application using cli? `java -cp <CLASS_APTH> YOUR_MAIN_CLASS`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the environment variable you're setting in your `.bash_profile` isn't getting picked up.

If you're running from **Eclipse**, you need to set environment variables manually on the Environment tab in the Run Configuration.

Go to `Run` -> `Run Configurations...`, find or create the run configuration for your app under `Java Applications`, go to the `Environment` tab and add your desired environment variables there.

Click the `Run` button and your program should print the environment variable as expected.

Comment: Eclipse may pick up your environment variables if you reboot. Worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782467/system-getenv-returns-null-when-the-environment-variable-exists

Comment: as I can see, we have to add case by case for each environment variable, is there anyway to import them from a file ?

Answer (score 1):

To set an environment variable, use the command "export varname=value", which sets the variable and exports it to the global environment (available to other processes). Enclosed the value with double quotes if it contains spaces.

You can set an environment variable permanently by placing an export command in your Bash shell startup script "~/.bashrc" (or "~/.bash_profile", or "~/.profile") of your home directory; or "/etc/profile" for system-wide operations.

If you use eclipse then you can set argument which used by jvm while running java program as

click right click on project name 
click Run as ----> Run Configuration --> click on argument tab from left upper corner.

Comment: Hi, there's program arguments and VM arguments, how should I set them? Could you provide a sample? Thanks!

Comment: @final static Please refere https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629641/how-to-set-google-application-credentials-for-google-compute-engine?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa this link !! hope this will helpful

Answer (score 0):

Print environnement variable return a map so try this to print all env variable :

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
    System.out.format("%s=%s%n", envName, env.get(envName));
}
```

Or just one :

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
String value = env.get("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
```

Comment: Hi, I have printed all the variables, but GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is not in the list. So, where exactly should I set this variable, so that java can read it?