# How to define GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS?

Tags: java, api, servlets, google-cloud-platform, credentials

My goal is to use one of the google cloud API's, for which I need that GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set to a .json file.

I receive this error message and a link on how to solve it:

> The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

After setting the variable through cmd (`set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\...\...\File.json`) to the .json file that I have just created, the same exact error continues appearing.

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT:

I'm using Eclipse JEE. I want to detect web entities from a local image using google cloud vision API. First using a html formulary I request the image and send it to a servlet class:
(index.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Tittle</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <h4>Upload an image: </h4>
    <div id="searchDiv">
        <form id="searchForm" action="webdetection" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div><input type="file" name="image" accept=".JPG, .JPEG, .PNG8, .PNG24, .GIF, .BMP, .WEBP, .RAW, .ICO, .PDF, .TIFF" required>
            </div>
            <div><input type="submit" name="searchBtn" value="Aceptar">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

These are the servlets and their mappings:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <web:description></web:description>
        <servlet-name>Web Detection</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>aiss.controller.google_vision.VisionServletController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Web Detection</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webdetection</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This is the Servlet for cloud vision:

```java
package aiss.controller.google_vision;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import aiss.model.CloudVision.DeteccionWeb;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;

public class VisionServletController extends HttpServlet {
    
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(VisionServletController.class.getName());
    
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        
        log.log(Level.FINE, "Processing GET request");
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(resp.getOutputStream());
        try {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        DeteccionWeb.detectWebDetectionsGcs(req.getRequestURL().toString(),ps);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            ps.println(e.toString());//this prints the previous error message I show
        }

    }
}
```

And the web detection class at which the servlet redirects:
(most of the imports aren't being used, but due to the class is being modified until it works, I don't know which classes I need)

```java
package aiss.model.CloudVision;

import com.google.api.gax.longrunning.OperationFuture;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateFileResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateFileResponse.Builder;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageRequest;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AsyncAnnotateFileRequest;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AsyncAnnotateFileResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AsyncBatchAnnotateFilesResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Block;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ColorInfo;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.CropHint;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.CropHintsAnnotation;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.DominantColorsAnnotation;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.FaceAnnotation;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Feature;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Feature.Type;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.GcsDestination;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.GcsSource;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Image;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageContext;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageSource;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.InputConfig;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.LocalizedObjectAnnotation;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.LocationInfo;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.OperationMetadata;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.OutputConfig;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Page;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Paragraph;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.SafeSearchAnnotation;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Symbol;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.TextAnnotation;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.WebDetection;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.WebDetection.WebEntity;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.WebDetection.WebImage;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.WebDetection.WebLabel;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.WebDetection.WebPage;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.WebDetectionParams;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Word;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class DeteccionWeb {
    
    /**
     * Detects whether the remote image on Google Cloud Storage has features you would want to
     * moderate.
     *
     * @param gcsPath The path to the remote on Google Cloud Storage file to detect web annotations.
     * @param out A {@link PrintStream} to write the results to.
     * @throws Exception on errors while closing the client.
     * @throws IOException on Input/Output errors.
     */
    public static void detectWebDetectionsGcs(String gcsPath, PrintStream out) throws Exception,
        IOException {
      List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();

      ImageSource imgSource = ImageSource.newBuilder().setImageUri(gcsPath).build();
      Image img = Image.newBuilder().setSource(imgSource).build();
      Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Type.WEB_DETECTION).build();
      AnnotateImageRequest request =
          AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder().addFeatures(feat).setImage(img).build();
      requests.add(request);

      try (ImageAnnotatorClient client = ImageAnnotatorClient.create()) {
        BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = client.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
        List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();

        for (AnnotateImageResponse res : responses) {
          if (res.hasError()) {
            out.printf("Error: %s\n", res.getError().getMessage());
            return;
          }

          // Search the web for usages of the image. You could use these signals later
          // for user input moderation or linking external references.
          // For a full list of available annotations, see http://g.co/cloud/vision/docs
          WebDetection annotation = res.getWebDetection();
          out.println("Entity:Id:Score");
          out.println("===============");
          for (WebEntity entity : annotation.getWebEntitiesList()) {
            out.println(entity.getDescription() + " : " + entity.getEntityId() + " : "
                + entity.getScore());
          }
          for (WebLabel label : annotation.getBestGuessLabelsList()) {
            out.format("\nBest guess label: %s", label.getLabel());
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

My main suspect is `ImageSource.newBuilder().setImageUri(gcsPath)`, as it seems cloud vision API may not work on http/https url's that doesn't belong to Google cloud storage. And it seems it can be solved with the credentials, but I can't pass through it.

Comment: What application are you running that expects to use this environment variable?  How are you starting that application?  Is the environment variable set in the environment in which the application is running?

Comment: Where are you running this code? On which platform/environment?

Comment: @kolban  post edited

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: @JesúsDíazCastro, you don't precise where you code is running? On your computer? Do you have gcloud installed?

Answer (score 1):

if you're using Tomcat in eclipse, the following thread should be helpful [How to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS for Google Compute Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629641/how-to-set-google-application-credentials-for-google-compute-engine).